Exercise 6.1 of Atiyah and Macdonald

i) Let $M$ be a Noetherian $A$-module and $u : M \to M$ a module homomorphism. If $u$ is surjective, then $u$ is an isomorphism.
ii) If $M$ is Artinian and $u$ is injective, then again $u$ is an isomorphism.
[For (i), consider the submodules $\text{Ker}(u^n)$; for (ii), the quotient modules $\text{Coker}(u^n)$.

(i) Consider ascending chain of submodules of $M$, $$\text{Ker}(u)\subseteq \text{Ker}(u^2)\subseteq \text{Ker}(u^3)\subseteq \cdots $$
Since $M$ is Noetherian, $\exists n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\text{Ker}(u^n)= \text{Ker}(u^{n+1})=\cdots$ (so on). Note $\text{Ker}(u^i)=(u^i
)^{-1}(0)=u^{-i}(0)$, for all $i$. So, in particular, $u^{-n}(0)=u^{-(n+1)}(0)$. Since $u$ is surjective, we have $u\circ u^{-1}=\text{id}_M$. Thus $$0=u^n\circ u^{-n}(0)=u^n\circ u^{-(n+1)}(0)=u^{-1}(0)=\text{Ker}(u).$$
Hence $u$ is an isomorphism.
(ii) is similar to (i) with descending chain $$\text{Im}(u)\supseteq \text{Im}(u^2)\supseteq \text{Im}(u^3)\supseteq \cdots$$ and $u$ is injective implies $u^{-1}\circ u=\text{id}_M$.
Given hint for (i) works. For (ii), I used submodules $\text{Im}(u^n)$ instead of $\text{Coker}(u^n)$. To be honest, I don’t see $\text{Coker}(u^i)\supseteq \text{Coker}(u^{i+1})$, and $\text{Coker}(u^n)= \text{Coker}(u^{n+1})$ implies $\text{Im}(u^n)=\text{Im}(u^{n+1})$.

The cokernel of $u^i$ does not contain the cokernel of $u^{i+1}$. Rather, because $\mathrm{Im}(u^{n+1})\subseteq \mathrm{Im}(u^n)$, it follows that $\mathrm{Coker}(u^n)$ is a quotient of $\mathrm{Im}(u^{n+1})$.

Is there a question anywhere here?

@ArturoMagidin Thank you for answer. I misinterpreted hint.

(should be "$\mathrm{Coker}(u^n)$ is a quotient of $\mathrm{Coker}(u^{n+1})$" )

Your proof of (i) is incorrect, because you don't yet know if $u^{-1}$ exists. Surjectivity gives you a set-theoretic right-inverse $v$, i.e. $u \circ v = \operatorname{id}_M$, but then you cannot conclude $v(0) = \operatorname{Ker}(u)$.

@red_trumpet perhaps $u^{-1}$ is an abuse of notation, I meant pre-image of subset of $M$. To be precise, if $u$ is surjective, then $u(u^{-1}(N))=N$ for all $N\subseteq M$.
